# How can I get the current (cached) history information for a TFS workspace when offline

Tags: batch-file, tfs, offline

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TF.EXE history C:\TFS\Project /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /Version:W

will give me machine parse-able details about the current workspace version.

This works great when connected to the Corporate LAN or VPN, but fails when offline.

I know TFPT connections allows the specification of the TFS connection to be offline, but the above operation still fails.

Is there a method from command line (so to be automated) to get this detail when offline?

Doing any operation within the context of the VS IDE is not usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible. The history command return the information of Changeset. It's stored in the TFS DATA tier.

When you are offline, you can’t connect to TFS sever through any tools or commands. Obviously, you can’t get it on the local computer either.

Comment: Ugh... I just don't know what to say without getting me kicked from this site for profanity. Thanks though.

Comment: If the work-space is configured for "Local" instead of "Server" is there an alternative?

Comment: Still regret，the difference between local workspace and server workspace only effect on  something like "no need to check out" , "Work offline easily", "Easily restore files that you have deleted locally ".  It has no effect on the storage method of the changeset information. The only way i can imagine, you  may need a copy of the Database on your local machine, get the information from it. First ,due to my lack SQL knowledge , cannot determine the feasibility. Second ,the most important, you can't ensure your copy Database always being the latest.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I would ask that they add this basic functionality, but there is just so much heartburn I have with TFSvc that I think their time would be better spent getting the gaps of functionality incorporated into their support of Git for TFS instead and EoL the TFSvc.